# Error using 'git add'

Tags: git

I want to commit the projects I have to my repository and I issued the following command:

```
$ git add README
```

I then get the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'README' did not match any files.
```

Does anyone know what I can do please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do in your folder.

```
ls
```

What do you get ?

It seems that README is not found in your folder.

Comment: Yeah, it now works. What I did was that I ran 'git init' in the folder and it works!